# Insert the control tab from one UI to another UI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[image: strong text]

I am new to python, the above figure is two UI, I was trying to insert the two tab from the right side UI into the left side UI. But I had met some error and no idea how to solve.
Now below is the original coding of the left side UI

```
import tkinter as tkk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os.path
import hashlib
import sys
import time
import getpass
from tkinter import filedialog
import platform
import getpass
import os,sys
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar
import Consts
import shutil
class Page(tkk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()
class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,bg='white')
       my_system=platform.uname()

#computer information
   comsys=my_system.system
   comnode=my_system.node
   comrel=my_system.release
   comver=my_system.version
   commac=my_system.machine
   compro=my_system.processor
   comuser=getpass.getuser()

   label1 = tkk.Label(self,  text="System: "+comsys,bg='white')
   label1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10,sticky='w')
   label2 = tkk.Label(self, text="Computer Name: "+comnode,bg='white')
   label2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=10,sticky='w')
   label3 = tkk.Label(self, text="Release: "+comrel,bg='white')
   label3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=10,sticky='w')
   label4 = tkk.Label(self, text="Version: "+comver,bg='white')
   label4.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=10,sticky='w')
   label5 = tkk.Label(self, text="Machine: "+commac,bg='white')
   label5.grid(row=5,column=1, pady=10,sticky='w')
   label6 = tkk.Label(self, text="Processor: "+compro,bg='white')
   label6.grid(row=6,column=1, pady=10,sticky='w')
   label7 = tkk.Label(self, text="Username: "+comuser,bg='white')
   label7.grid(row=7,column=1,pady=10,sticky='w')

#computer usage hold first, no idea how to do

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,bg='white')

   tabControl=ttk.Notebook(self)
   
   qsFrame = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   fsFrame = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   csFrame = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   
   #tab
   tabControl.add(qsFrame, text='Quick Scan')
   tabControl.add(fsFrame, text='Full Scan')
   tabControl.add(csFrame, text='Custom Scan')

   tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill="both")


class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,bg='white')
       label = tkk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
       label.grid(row=2,column=1)
       def mytools():
            total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")
            print("Total:%d GB" %(total // (2**30)))
            print("Used:%d GB" %(used // (2**30)))
            print("Free:%d GB" %(free // (2**30)))

            if free <= total/2:
                clean = os.popen('Cleanmgr.exe/ sagerun:1').read()
                #print(clean)
   def btn1():
        if __name__ =="__main__":
            mytools()
   button1=ttk.Button(self,text="Clean Up",command=btn1)
   button1.grid(row=3,column=2)

class Page4(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,bg='white')
       label = tkk.Label(self, text="This is page 4")
       label.grid(row=2,column=1)       

class MainView(tkk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)
        p4 = Page4(self)

        buttonframe = tkk.Frame(self)
        container = tkk.Frame(self,bg='white')
        buttonframe.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        buttonframe.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        buttonframe.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p4.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    
        stats_btn = tkk.PhotoImage(file='C:/FYP/SecuCOM2022/icon&pic/stats.png')
        scanner_btn = tkk.PhotoImage(file='C:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\icon&pic\scanner.png')
        speedup_btn = tkk.PhotoImage(file='C:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\icon&pic\speedup.png')
        settings_btn = tkk.PhotoImage(file='C:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\icon&pic\settings.png')
    
        #logo
        logo=tkk.PhotoImage(file="C:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\icon&pic\g (1).png")
        label=tkk.Label(buttonframe,image=logo)
        label.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10,pady=10)
        logo.image = logo

        b1 = tkk.Button(buttonframe, image=stats_btn, command=p1.show, borderwidth=0)
        b2 = tkk.Button(buttonframe, image=scanner_btn, command=p2.show, borderwidth=0)
        b3 = tkk.Button(buttonframe, image=speedup_btn, command=p3.show, borderwidth=0)
        b4 = tkk.Button(buttonframe, image=settings_btn, command=p4.show, borderwidth=0)

        b1.image = stats_btn
        b2.image = scanner_btn
        b3.image = speedup_btn
        b4.image = settings_btn

        b1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        b2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        b3.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        b4.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root= Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    main.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    main.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    root.title("SecuCOM2022")
    root.geometry("600x300")
    root.maxsize(600,375)
    root.minsize(600,375)
    root.iconbitmap('C:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\icon&pic\g.png')
    root.mainloop()


root.mainloop()
#GUI end`
```

Next below here is the right side UI coding, there are multiple files for it. I just show files related with the UI only.

Consts.py

```
ENTRY_WIDTH = 50
```

FileReportTab.py

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar
import time
import os.path
import sys
from VTPackage import Consts
class FileReportTab:

def __init__(self, root, frame, vtClient):
    self.root = root
    self.frame = frame
    self.vtClient = vtClient

    self.mainVTURLframe = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text=' File report')
    self.mainVTURLframe.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=8, pady=4)

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Progress:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainVTURLframe, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='determinate')
    self.progressBar.grid(column=1, row=1)

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="File path:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.filePath = StringVar()
    filePathEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=self.filePath, state='readonly')
    filePathEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Status:").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.status = StringVar()
    statusEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=self.status, state='readonly')
    statusEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Positive Indications:").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.positiveIndications = StringVar()
    positiveIndicationsEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=self.positiveIndications, state='readonly')
    positiveIndicationsEntry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="SHA1:").grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.sha1 = StringVar()
    sha1Entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=self.sha1, state='readonly')
    sha1Entry.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="SHA256:").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    self.sha256 = StringVar()
    sha256Entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=self.sha256, state='readonly')
    sha256Entry.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky='W')

    chooseFileButton = ttk.Button(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Choose File", width=40, command=self._scanFile).grid(column=1, row=0)

    self.scanCheckingTimeInterval = 25000  # This is the amount of time we are going to wait before asking VT again if it already processed our scan request

    for child in self.mainVTURLframe.winfo_children():
        child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=2)

def showResults(self, results):
    try:
        #self.file_Path = self.filePath
        self.sha1.set(results["sha1"])
        self.sha256.set(results["sha256"])
        self.positiveIndications.set(results["positives"]) 
        if results["positives"] == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning("Analysis Info","File is Safe.\nOur Scanners found nothing Malicious")
        elif results["positives"] <= 5:
            messagebox.showwarning("Analysis Alert", "Given File may be Malicious")
        elif results["positives"] >= 5:
            messagebox.showwarning("Analysis Alert", f"Given File is Malicious.\nAdvice you remove the file from your System!")
            res = messagebox.askyesno("Analysis Alert","The given file is highly Malicious.\nDo you want to Delete it permanently?")
            if res == 1:
                print("Attemting to delete file...")
                time.sleep(1)
                os.remove(self.filePath1)
                
                #if os.PathLike(_scanFile.filePath):
                 #   os.remove(self.filePath)
            else:
                print("This file cannot be deleted. Please do not use the fie. It's Malicious")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', e)

def checkStatus(self):
    try:
        self.scanResult = self.vtClient.get_file_report(self.scanID)
        print(self.scanResult)
        if self.scanResult["response_code"] == -2:  # By reading the next line, you can understand what is the meaning of the -2 response ode
            self.status.set("Scanning...")
            self.progressBar['value'] = self.progressBar['value'] + 5
            self.root.update_idletasks()
            self.mainVTURLframe.after(self.scanCheckingTimeInterval, self.checkStatus)

        else:
            self.hasScanFinished = True
            self.showResults(self.scanResult)
            self.status.set("Finished!")

            self.progressBar['value'] = 100
    except Exception as e:
        if "To much API requests" in str(e):
            pass

def _scanFile(self):
    try:
        self.progressBar['value'] = 0
        self.filePath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file for VT", filetypes=(("EXE files", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))

        if (self.filePath):  # Only if the user chose a file, we will want to continue the process
            self.filePath.set(self.filePath1)
            self.status.set("Sending file...")
            self.progressBar['value'] = 10
            
            self.root.update_idletasks()
            self.scanID = self.vtClient.scan_file(self.filePath1)
            self.hasScanFinished = False
            if not self.hasScanFinished:
                self.scanResult = self.vtClient.get_file_report(self.scanID)
                print(self.scanResult)
                self.checkStatus()
                # We could have been using time.sleep() or time.wait(), but then our UI would get stuck.
                # by using after, we are initiating a callback in which does not blocks our event loop
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', e)
```

URLreportTab.py

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar
from VTPackage import Consts

class URLreportTab:
def __init__(self, root, frame, vtClient):
    self.root = root
    self.frame = frame
    self.mainVTURLframe = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text=' URL report tab!')

    # using the tkinter grid layout manager
    self.mainVTURLframe.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)
    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="URL:").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')  # What does sticky does?      Sticky sayes where to stick the label to : N,S,E,W
    urlEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH)
    urlEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='E')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Positive Indications:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    Positive = StringVar()
    PositiveEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=Positive, state='readonly')
    PositiveEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.mainVTURLframe, text="Detections:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')  # <== right-align
    detections = StringVar()
    detectionsEntry = ttk.Entry(self.mainVTURLframe, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=detections, state='readonly')
    detectionsEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='W')

    self.notificationFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text=' Notifications', width=40)
    # using the tkinter grid layout manager
    self.notificationFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=8, pady=10, sticky='W')

    ttk.Label(self.notificationFrame, text="Errors:").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')  # <== increment row for each
    Error = StringVar()
    ErrorEntry = ttk.Entry(self.notificationFrame, width=Consts.ENTRY_WIDTH, textvariable=Error, state='readonly')

    ErrorEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='W')

    def _cleanErrorMessage():  # We could have been doing this without a function, but it is more neat that way
        Error.set("")

    def _getReport():
        # the _ notation before a function means that this function is internal to the class only. As python cannot really prevent you from using it outside the class (as C# for example) the notation is being used to warn other developers not to call this function outside the class
        try:
            _cleanErrorMessage()  # Starting with cleaning the error message bar
            if not urlEntry.get():
                print('Please enter a URL')
                Error.set("Please enter a URL!")
                return

            urlToCheck = urlEntry.get()
            response = vtClient.get_url_report(urlToCheck)
            print(response)
            Positive.set(response["positives"])
            scans = response["scans"]

            findings = set()
            for key, value in scans.items():
                if value["detected"]:
                    findings.add(value["result"])
            detections.set(",".join([str(finding) for finding in findings]))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            Error.set(e)

    checkURLinVTButton = ttk.Button(self.mainVTURLframe, text='Check Now!', command=_getReport).grid(column=2, row=0)

    # Instead of setting padding for each UI element, we can just iterate through the children of the main UI object.
    for child in self.mainVTURLframe.winfo_children():
        child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=2)
    for child in self.notificationFrame.winfo_children():
        child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=2)
```

VTApp.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import configparser
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

from VTPackage import URLreportTab
from VTPackage import FileReportTab

from VTPackage import VTClient

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

class VTApp:
def __init__(self):
    # Loading the config file
    self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    self.config.read('config.ini')
    self.virusTotalAPIkey = config['VirusTotal']['apiKey']

    self.vtClient = VTClient.VTClient(self.virusTotalAPIkey)
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.title("Virus Total UI")
    self.menuBar = Menu()
    self.root.config(menu=self.menuBar)
    self.fileMenu = Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
    self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
    self.fileMenu.add_separator()
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)

    if not self.vtClient.is_API_key_valid():
        messagebox.showerror('Error', "API key is not valid! Check your config file")

    def _quit():
        self.root.quit()  # The app  will exist when this function is called
        self.root.destroy()
        exit()

    self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)  # command callback
    self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.root)  # Create Tab Control

    self.urlFrame = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
    self.urlTab = URLreportTab.URLreportTab(self.root, self.urlFrame, self.vtClient)
    self.tabControl.add(self.urlFrame, text='URL')

    self.fileFrame = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
    self.fileTab = FileReportTab.FileReportTab(self.tabControl, self.fileFrame, self.vtClient)
    self.tabControl.add(self.fileFrame, text='File')

    self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible

def start(self):
    self.root.mainloop()
```

Main.py

```
from VTPackage import VTApp

vtApp = VTApp.VTApp()
vtApp.start()
```

This is the original code, Sorry for the spacing error, I copy&paste from vsc and it seem like the got some spacing error after Class. So basically this is the original code and I try like import VTApp and code inside class Page2 like

```
vtApp = VTApp.VTApp()
vtApp.start()
```

and change some coding in the VTApp.py but it doesn't work.... Does anyone know how to make the script works? I been trying and trying for a week and still couldn't get the solution.

Comment: provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also, explain what you want in better way.

Comment: You've posted far too much code. If the question is about moving a notebook tab from one window to another, we only need two windows, two notebooks, and a couple of tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move a widget from one window to another in tkinter. You will have to recreate the tab in the other window.

Comment: Thanks for that, I finally understand and it works already, Thank you